# Creating a Web Interface for Raspberry Pi Display

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, webserver, rgb

I have a Raspberry Pi running a Web server and I'd like to be able to create a web interface to change the colors and images on my RGB display.

I control the RGB display by navigating to the directory and executing a python file and it lights up, it ends up looking like

```
pi@raspberrypi: sudo python test.py
```

Cool, it works! But how can I execute this on my pi webserver, I don't even know where to begin. What sort of framework can I use to accomplish my goal here?

Answer (score 2):

You could use for example [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/). I like flask, which i use on my webserver. By the way it is also an Raspberry Pi. I think the most framework have a developer server, so you haven‘t set up a ‚real‘ webserver.

Maybe you could use Jupyter Notebook too, but i didn‘t try it on my Pi.